# Creating both an external and internal IP using ansible and gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I'm using Ansible 2.9.1 to create some compute instances using GCP. I would like to create an external IP for each instance, which I've managed to do using the following code:

```
  - name: create an instance
    gcp_compute_instance:
      name: "{{ compute_inst }}"
      machine_type: "{{ machine }}"
      disks:
      - auto_delete: 'true'
        boot: 'true'
        source: "{{ disk }}"
      network_interfaces:
        - access_configs:
          - name: External NAT
            nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
            type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
      zone: "{{ zone }}"
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      state: present
    register: instance
```

where address is an external `gcp_compute_address`. However, I would also like to set a static internal IP. According to the ansible `gcp_compute_instance` [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_instance_module.html) you should be able to set **network_ip** in the **network_interfaces** list:

> An IPv4 internal network address to assign to the instance for this network interface. If not specified by the user, an unused internal IP is assigned by the system.

I've tried this using the following code:

```
  - name: create an instance
    gcp_compute_instance:
      name: "{{ compute_inst }}"
      machine_type: "{{ machine }}"
      disks:
      - auto_delete: 'true'
        boot: 'true'
        source: "{{ disk }}"
      network_interfaces:
        - access_configs:
          - name: External NAT
            nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
            type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
        - network_ip: "{{ internal_ip }}" 
      zone: "{{ zone }}"
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      state: present
    register: instance
```

where `internal_ip` is a string containing an internal IP address. When I run the playbook I get the following error:

```
Networks must be distinct for NICs attached to a VM.
```

So I read through the documentation again and found the following for **network_interfaces**:

> An array of configurations for this interface. This specifies how this interface is configured to interact with other network services, such as connecting to the internet. Only one network interface is supported per instance.

I am able to create an instance using the GCP console where I can get both an external and specify an internal IP. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong in ansible or any suggestions what to try?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_module.html), `network_ip` is a key that is part of the same dictionary as `access_configs`.

In your case, you have two items in the `network_interfaces` list, which gets translated into configurations for two different network interfaces.

Can you try with this version? (I have removed the dash in front of `network_ip`, making it part of the same list item as `access_configs`):

```
  - name: create an instance
    gcp_compute_instance:
      name: "{{ compute_inst }}"
      machine_type: "{{ machine }}"
      disks:
      - auto_delete: 'true'
        boot: 'true'
        source: "{{ disk }}"
      network_interfaces:
        - access_configs:
          - name: External NAT
            nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
            type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
          network_ip: "{{ internal_ip }}" 
      zone: "{{ zone }}"
      project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
      state: present
    register: instance
```